# MySQL replication not create trigger in slaves machines

Tags: mysql, triggers, replication

I have a MySQL ROW Based Replication with one master and multiples slaves but I can't have triggers on slaves.
My problem is: When I create one trigger in Master I can´t create the same Trigger in slaves.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: can you provide the trigger query which you want to add to slave and it is not replicating. Elobrate in detail

Comment: The problem is, when I execute a trigger create command in master the create comand CAN'T replicate in SLAVES.